# Unable to run the Qt application as a stand alone application

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, virtualbox, qt5.5

**Steps I have tried to create stand alone web application**

Host PC is Ubuntu 14.04, 64 bit OS.

Qt version - Qt5.6.

Testing on the virtual Box Ubuntu 14.04, 64 bit OS.

Application is working properly in the Host PC.

I copied all the web dependent files & process, platform dependent files and the lib files where the executable file is present, then I redirected the library path to the Present working directory of the executable.

```
command used : chrpath -r ./lib AppName
```

then when i run the application its breaking as

```
This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "xcb".
Available platform plugins are: xcb.
Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I ran the ldd on libqxcb.so to find the dependent files.

```
command : ldd libqxcb.so
```

I solved this by manually coping the "not found files"  to /usr/lib path

```
libQt5XcbQpa.so.5 
libQt5DBus.so.5
libQt5Core.so.5
libQt5Gui.so.5
```

Now the application is breaking due to the below error :

```
QXcbIntegration: Cannot create platform OpenGL context, neither GLX nor EGL are enabled
Qt WebEngine data directory not found at location /home/user/Qt5.5.1/5.5/gcc_64. Trying application directory...
Qt WebEngine Plugins directory not found. Trying fallback directory... Plugins as for example video codecs MAY NOT work.
Installed Qt WebEngine locales directory not found at location /home/user/Qt5.5.1/5.5/gcc_64/translations/qtwebengine_locales. Trying application directory...
Qt WebEngine data directory not found at location /home/user/Qt5.5.1/5.5/gcc_64. Trying application directory...
Qt WebEngine Plugins directory not found. Trying fallback directory... Plugins as for example video codecs MAY NOT work.
Installed Qt WebEngine locales directory not found at location /home/user/Qt5.5.1/5.5/gcc_64/translations/qtwebengine_locales. Trying application directory...
QXcbIntegration: Cannot create platform OpenGL context, neither GLX nor EGL are enabled
QXcbIntegration: Cannot create platform OpenGL context, neither GLX nor EGL are enabled
QOpenGLWidget: Failed to create context
QXcbIntegration: Cannot create platform OpenGL context, neither GLX nor EGL are enabled
QOpenGLWidget: Failed to create context
composeAndFlush: makeCurrent() failed
composeAndFlush: makeCurrent() failed
composeAndFlush: makeCurrent() failed
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Can anyone guide me to solve above problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a desktop version of Ubuntu running in virtual box?

Have you enabled "Enabled 3D Acceleration" in the VM options.

Have you installed the Virtualbox video drivers?

The issue is QtWebengine needs OpenGL to work that is why you are getting this error:

```
QXcbIntegration: Cannot create platform OpenGL context, neither GLX nor EGL are enabled
```